# Possible to get Sharepoint 2010 working with IE6?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, internet-explorer-6, cross-browser

I work for a fairly large government organization where about 60% of the users are still on IE6.  Microsoft is very clear that IE6 is not compatible with Sharepoint 2010, but as a quick fix until we can upgrade people to IE8, I'd like to see if there is a way to make some changes to get it working with IE6.

Does anyone know if this has been done by anyone?  Any suggestions on where to look/start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this, although I won't recommend it:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/4534/how-to-make-sharepoint-2010-page-compatible-in-ie-6-0

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/3b14dbd5-147a-4a38-b1b6-7e1b33d94319/

Answer (score 1):

I would use this situation as a hard reason why your company needs to go ahead and make the switch to a newer browser.  Often in large organizations, they don't upgrade because they simply don't need to and they wait for a scenario in which it's required.  In this case, they need to and so I'd use it as the excuse to get that ball rolling.

Instead of hacking up SharePoint 2010 to work with IE6, which is a solid waste of effort, I've spent time building custom controls to warn IE6 users that their browser won't work on the site.  You're better off not spending a lot of time and money to customize SharePoint to work on a browser that's 10 years old, not supported by the product, and that you'll be replacing anyway.

Comment: Tell that to the guy who signs my paycheck.  Maybe you'll have better luck than I did...

Comment: Logic and reason doesn't work in every situation, which we're all well aware of.  That doesn't mean the right information isn't worth providing and discussing.

Comment: +1 to hint towards what should be done, no matter costs. It would be interesting to hear what happened with this, Abe.